# "Powershell Module Unavailable" error trying to connect to minikube

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, containers, kubectl, minikube

This is the error am getting, please help me anyone.

> Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running pre
>   create checks.
>   : Hyper-V PowerShell Module is not available

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the Hyper-V PowerShell Module then

Comment: Thanks for response I installed powershell module but still am getting same error. Can you please give me a source to install minikube am trying to do all types like chocaltey and  docker. Am not able to acheive

Answer (score 0):

I confirm issue.
Looking at code:
powershell.go in recent minikube

```
func hypervAvailable() error {
    stdout, err := cmdOut("@(Get-Command hyper-v\\Get-VM).ModuleName")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    resp := parseLines(stdout)
    if resp[0] != "Hyper-V" {
        return ErrNotInstalled
    }

    return nil
}
```

and simple check on my box gives

```
C:\Users\slavko> (Get-Command hyper-v\Get-VM).ModuleName
hyper-v
```

So that check is quite silly, as that check in Go is case sensitive.

UPD: Code above is fixed 10 hrs ago. Check 0.25.2